# WebHook Azure Data Factory pass variables

Tags: json, azure, azure-data-factory, webhooks

I have a WebHook activity in Azure Data Factory pipeline but I'm not able to pass variables here.

```
@json('{
"body": "@{pipeline().parameters.body}",
"name": "@{variables('name')}"
}')
```

There is a problem with `'`. I've tried with `\'name\'` but it does not work.

Comment: unfortunatelly it does not work. I needed to do it as below:
@json(concat('{
"name": "',variables('name'),'"
}'))

Comment: Please check updated, I've tested it in pipeline run successfully.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The body representing the payload to be be sent to endpoint must be Valid JSON or an expression that results a value of type JSON. So in WebHook activity you can just pass the JSON string rather than using the function `json()` again.

Checkout this example:

**Use any string variable:**

[image]
[image]

**Using the variable and parameter in JSON string:**

```
{
   "var":"@{variables('variable')}",
   "param":"@{pipeline().parameters.parameter}",
   "age":"23"
}
```

[image]

**by string interpolation, the value of variable is replaced in place**

[image]